# jQuery UI error with flex slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, flexslider

I am Integrated a sliding tab on a page but there is error with jqueryui.js When i remove UI js then flex slider is working but sliding tab error. and when i used jqueryui.js the slide tab is working but flex slider is stop.

Below is our demo url in which i integrated both flex slider and UI tab

```
http://demo5.vivacityinfotech.net/magento/flex-slider
```

When i remove the jquery-ui. js file then i got below error:

```
TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```

Any one have idea to resolve this issue then please share with me.

Comment: Can you please check the source of my reference link and i have already included that http://demo5.vivacityinfotech.net/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/vivacity_socialconnect/socialFeeds/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Flex slider and UI tab are conflicting due to jquery-ui.js file . How i can resolve ?

Comment: Please check my reference link.